# Can I use the Set command globally?

Tags: vba, excel

I have several subs that use

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook

Set s1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

I'm looking to move all the Dim statements out to a new module and make them globals (or would it better to make them public at place the top of the module they are currently contained in?).

Is there a way to do this the Set statements so I don't need this same line in each sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general code module (`insert->module`) enter something like this:

```
Public wb1 As Workbook
Public s1 As Worksheet
Public s2 As Worksheet 'etc.
Public Initialized As Boolean

Sub Initialize()
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set s1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set s2 = wb1.Sheets(2)
    Initialized = True
End Sub
```

Then in the `ThisWorkbook` code module, have:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Initialize
End Sub
```

Then (mostly as a safety in case something (e.g. a run-time error) resets the project) include the line

```
If Not Initialized Then Initialize
```

at the top of every sub that needs access to those variables.

Having said all this -- heavy use of global variables is considered by many to be poor design. On the other hand -- if they are variables that you use throughout the project and they never change their reference then something like this could cut down on the code clutter.

Comment: Agree with all points - @JasonTempleman especially note that as mentioned by John, you shouldn't be declaring global variables simply for the sake of 'cleaning up' the layout of your code. Generally it is better design to only declare your variables near when you will use them. Otherwise a giant block of 'Dim' statements will require a lot of comments to be understandable by a user. Also don't do this as an excuse to not think about which variables need to be used where, or to avoid passing variables between functions/subs.